# Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in ')(-1.3')

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've only encountered this error now. How do I resolve it, and where in the code is the error located? I've attached the image of the code as well.

```
\begin{tasks}[style=itemize, label=\Alph*., after-item-skip=10pt, label-width = 2em, item-indent = 27pt](2)
\task \\ \begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,axis on top,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-1.45,ymax=2,ytick={-4},yticklabels={$-4$}, xtick={1.5},xticklabels={$2$}] \addplot[smooth,color=black] coordinates{(\empty) (-1.3,-0.2)} node {$-2$};\end{axis}
\draw[ultra thick] (1.2,5) .. controls (1.4,4) and (1.8,2.4) .. (2.3,2.4);\draw[ultra thick] (3.5,3.7) .. controls (3.2,3.8) and (2.8,2.4) .. (2.3,2.4);\draw[ultra thick] (3.5,3.7) .. controls (3.7,3.8) and (4.1,2.4) .. (4.6,2.4);\draw[ultra thick] (5.7,5.2) .. controls (5.5,4.1) and (5.1,2.4) .. (4.6,2.4); \node at (3.7,2.1) {$0$};\end{tikzpicture}
\task \\ \begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,axis on top,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-1.45,ymax=2,ytick={-4},yticklabels={$-4$}, xtick={1.5},xticklabels={$2$}]  \addplot[smooth,color=black] coordinates{(\empty)(-1.3,-0.2)} node {$-2$};\end{axis}
\draw[ultra thick] (1.2,5) .. controls (1.4,4) and (1.8,2.4) .. (2.3,2.4);
\draw[ultra thick] (5.7,5.2) .. controls (5.5,4.1) and (5.1,2.4) .. (4.6,2.4);\node at (3.7,2.1) {$0$};\end{tikzpicture}
\task \\ \begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,axis on top,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-1.45,ymax=2,ytick={-4},yticklabels={$-4$}, xtick={1.6},xticklabels={$2$}]  \addplot[smooth,color=black] coordinates{(\empty)(-1.3,-0.2)} node {$-2$};\node at (3.7,2.1) {$0$};\end{axis}
\draw[ultra thick] (.4,4) .. controls (1.6,4) and (2.25,2.2) .. (2.15,2.4);
\draw[ultra thick] (3.5,3.7) .. controls (3.2,3.8) and (2.4,3) .. (2.15,2.4);
\draw[ultra thick] (3.5,3.7) .. controls (4.3,3.2) and (4.93,2.5) .. (4.8,2.4);
\draw[ultra thick] (6.7,4.2) .. controls (5.5,3.8) and (5.1,2.9) .. (4.8,2.4);\node at (3.7,2.1) {$0$};\end{tikzpicture}
\task \\ \begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,axis on top,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-1.4,ymax=2,ytick={-4},yticklabels={$-4$}, xtick={1.65},xticklabels={$2$}]  \addplot[smooth,color=black] coordinates{(\empty)(-1.3,-0.2)} node {$-2$};\end{axis}
\draw[ultra thick] (.4,4.2) .. controls (2,4) and (2.2,2) .. (2.2,2.4);
\draw[ultra thick] (6.7,4.2) .. controls (5.5,3.8) and (5.1,2.9) .. (4.8,2.35);
\node at (3.7,2.1) {$0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tasks}
```

[image]

Comment: Comment out piece by piece until the error goes. Then you will know where it is. Also, when you post here, it is expected that the example given is compilable so that people do not have to work so much to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focused just on the images:

- I would draw them as pure `tikzpicture`s
- Curve in picture is better (and simpler) to draw as one line with defined directions relative to given coordinates. For example the code for the first `tikzpicture` can be:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{lbl/.style = {below, fill=white, font=\footnotesize}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% axis
\draw   (-3,0) -- ++(6,0) node[below left] {$x$}
        (0,-1) -- ++(0,5) node[below left] {$y$};
\foreach \x in {-2,0,2}
    \draw   (0.5*\x,0.1) -- ++ (0,-0.2) node[lbl] {$\x$};
\draw[very thick, red] 
        (-2,3) .. controls +(0.2,-1) and +(-0.5,0)  .. (-1,0)
               .. controls +(0.5,0)  and +(-0.3,0)  .. (0,1)
               .. controls +(0.3,0)  and +(-0.5,0)  .. (1,0)
               .. controls +(0.5,0)  and +(-0.2,-1) .. (2,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On similar way you can draw other  pictures. When there the curves contains two (not connected) segments, draw each of them separately.

Of course, you can draw this image as `pgfplots` diagram. But in this case is handy to define  function and its domain which you like to draw.